# Finding duplicates SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let me first give some example table table which will make my question easier to understand.

```
Column1      Column2      Column3
Valuea       Value123     Value456
Valueax      Value123     Value456
Valueb       Value123     Value456
Valueb       Value123     Value456

select   Column1,
     Column2,
         Column3,
         count(*)
from     ColumnName
group by 
     Column1,
     Column2,
     Column3,
having   count(Count2+Count3) > 1
```

I want to return 'column1', 'column2', 'column3' where column 2and3 will contain more than more duplicates but 'column1' must be different. So at present the above code would return:

```
Valueb       Value123     Value456 2
```

but i want it to return

```
Valuea       Value123     Value456
Valueax      Value123     Value456
```

where column1 has different values but column2 and column3 values are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't group by concatenating. This will treat 'xxx' + 'yyy' the same as 'x' + 'xxyyy'. How about getting

```
;WITH x AS 
(
   SELECT Column2, Column3 
   FROM dbo.table GROUP BY Column2, Column3
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT t.Column1, t.Column2, t.Column3
FROM x INNER JOIN dbo.table AS t
ON x.Column2 = t.Column2
AND x.Column3 = t.Column3
GROUP BY t.Column1, t.Column2, t.Column3
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

This assumes that none of these columns are NULLable.

Comment: Note that if you have three rows and some are duplicates (e.g. `Valuea`, `Valueax` and `Valueax`) the latter two won't be reported... if these are potential cases you'll need to supply more sample data and how you want to handle those cases.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,

You want to have unique row record for your table.
Instead of using `Group By` who Aaron mentioned you can't use in concatenating.

However , you can use `Over` to do that.

**UPDATE** : you need to consider what are you need to group together as Aaron mentioned "x" + "yy" is identical with "xy" + "y"

```
With Data AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over 
     (Partition By "Key" Order by "Key") as R,
     Column1, Column2, Column3
)
SELECT * FROM Data 
WHERE R = 1
```

Comment: `Partition By Column1+Column2+Column3`? That is rather dangerous. `'x' + 'yy' + 'z'` will be treated the same as `'xy' + 'y' + 'z'` but I don't consider those rows identical. In any case even if you ignore that I don't think this gives the desired result - why `WHERE R = 1`?

Comment: I didn't notice that after read your post. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Still don't see how this could possibly derive the desired result.